# Unstable bluetooth connection between BQ ubuntu phone and car kit

Tags: bluetooth

I am unable to get a stable connection between my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition phone and my car kit. The phone is recognisedby the car as a device, it is paired and synchronised, but the bluetooth connection is severed approximately 20 seconds  after synching. At the same time the BQ Phone starts searching for/connecting to new devices.

The BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition runs on Ubuntu 14.10 (r21) and my car is a Volvo V50. Connections to the car kit work well with Android, Windows and Apple phones.

What should I do (differently) to create a stable bluetooth connection and be able to make calls in my car?

Comment: Pls see bug report, which look identical to the issue you are having.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1435040 You can on the top press "This bug affects X person. Does this bug affect you?"